# How do I get the string array from a Notification bundle?

Tags: android, notifications, bundle

I have an app that reads notifications to the driver while driving.  I am trying to parse the various notifications.  Those that use the old 'tickerText' work fine but several apps like Skype don't support that.  Instead, the text in the notification after the first message just says something like "3 new messages".  Not very helpful.  I want the last message string instead.  I wrote this:

```
public class Catcher extends NotificationListenerService {

File file;
String dir;
File save;
int count = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/NotCatch";
    save = new File(dir);
    if(!save.exists()){
        save.mkdirs();
    }

    //Toast.makeText(this, dir + " " + file.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    super.onNotificationPosted(sbn);

    file = new File(save, "NotCatch" + count + ".txt");
    count++;
    String temp = "";
    String[] lines;
    Notification not = sbn.getNotification();
    temp += "Category: " + not.category+ "\n";
    temp+= "TickerText: " + not.tickerText + "\n";

    temp += "Extras..."+ "\n";
    Bundle bun = not.extras;
    temp+= "BigText: " + bun.getString(Notification.EXTRA_BIG_TEXT)+ "\n";
    temp+= "SummaryText: " + bun.getString(Notification.EXTRA_SUMMARY_TEXT)+ "\n";
    temp+= "InfoText: " + bun.getString(Notification.EXTRA_INFO_TEXT)+ "\n";
    temp+= "Text: " + bun.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT)+ "\n";
    temp+= "TextLines: " + bun.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT_LINES)+ "\n";
    temp+= "SubText: " + bun.getString(Notification.EXTRA_SUB_TEXT) + "\n";
    temp+= "Title:" + bun.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE) +"\n";
    temp+= "Big Title:" + bun.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE_BIG) +"\n";


/*    lines = bun.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT_LINES).split("\n");

    temp += "Lines... \n" ;

    int cnt = 0;
    for (String line : lines) {
        temp+= cnt + ": " + line + "\n";
        cnt++;
    }*/



    Looper.prepare();
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write(temp.getBytes());
        fos.close();
        Toast.makeText(this,"File written", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

This is just what I have so far for testing of course.  I can get the bundle from the notification but it can't get the string array of the message lines.  It looks like this in the debugger. 'bun' below is the 'Bundle' from the 'Notification'.
[image: Debugger]

My question is this.  How do I get the array of strings that start with "some message text - 4"?  This is the bundle from an Android Notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally was able to get the strings this way

```
 CharSequence[] lines = bun.getCharSequenceArray(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT_LINES);
    for(CharSequence line : lines){
        temp+= "line: " + line.toString() + "\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the strings you are trying to retrieve are contained in the ArrayMap mMap (according to the debugger image), and as implementations of Map are serializable, you'll want to do the following to first retrieve that map:

```
ArrayMap map = bun.getSerializableExtra("mMap");
```

Then, you should be able to get the array of strings you want (which according to the debugger image is an array of CharSequence objects) with the following:

```
CharSequence[] messages = (CharSequence[]) map.valueAt(1);
```

---

- An interesting read on bundles and maps:
  https://medium.com/the-wtf-files/the-mysterious-case-of-the-bundle-and-the-map-7b15279a794e#.kf3m2haa3

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I gave that a try but it did not compile.  However, it is hopefully leading in the right direction.  Investigation continues...

Comment: You might need to cast the bun.getSerializableExtra to ArrayMap. Presumably Android Studio will show you why it won't compile?